# How to set a specific tab always active in Material tab group while opening Bootstrap Modal multiple times?

Tags: angular-material

I used Material tab group in Bootstrap Modal. I always want the 2nd tab active. If I set `[selectedIndex]='1'`, I get the 2nd tab active while opening the modal first time. But after opening first time, if I select 3rd tab and close the modal and reopen the modal, I get the 3rd tab active, not the 2nd tab.

How can I always get the 2nd tab active while opening the modal?

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="exampleModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]='1'>
          <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
          <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
          <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any resolution for this issue?

Comment: no, nothing yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bug but you can use 2 way data binding, it works

```
<md-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="selectedIndex">
```

In your ts file:

```
selectedIndex: number = 1;
```

and you have to set selectedIndex value on click of your modal button like this:

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bootstrap" data-keyboard="false" (click)="selectedIndex = 1">
    Open Modal
</button>
```